# How to Get back/Return to a loop after catching a exceptional

Tags: java, loops, try-catch

I have this code that computes an Exponential example 3⁴ = 81.0 and the codes ask the user on how many numbers and exponent he wants to enter and when the user inputs numbers and exponents and he input an invalid input a letter the code will catch the java.util.InputMismatchException and stop. Are there any codes that can go back to the input numbers and exponent to enter again?

I've tried the boolean thing but it's not working and I'm searching about this thing but no one work.

```
    try {
        String[] unicode = {"\u2070", "\u00b9", "\u00b2", "\u00b3", "\u2074", "\u2075", "\u2076", "\u2077", "\u2078", "\u2079"};

        System.out.print("Enter how many Numbers and Exponent you want to enter: ");
        int userNum = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
        ArrayList<Integer> num = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < userNum; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter a Number: ");
            int userNumber = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
            num.add(userNumber);
            System.out.print("Enter the exponent: ");
            int userExponent = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
            nums.add(userExponent);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < userNum; i++) {
            double answer = num.get(i);
            for (int x = 0; x < nums.get(i) - 1; x++) {
                answer *= num.get(i);
            }
            System.out.print(num.get(i));
            for (int x = 0; x < String.valueOf(nums.get(i)).length(); x++) {
                char g = String.valueOf(nums.get(i)).charAt(x);
                String h = String.valueOf(g);
                System.out.print(unicode[Integer.parseInt(h)]);
            }
            System.out.println(" = " + answer);
        }
    } catch (InputMismatchException exception) {
        System.out.println(exception+" Invalid Input. Numbers Only.");
    }
}
```

What I expect to this is when the user inputs an invalid input the program will catch java.util.InputMismatchException and print it and go back to inputs to input again

Ex.

Enter Num:12

Enter Exponent:asd

java.util.InputMismatchException

Enter Exponent:123

Comment: You probably want to have the `try/catch` in the loop, not the other way. When there's an exception in the loop in this case, the loop is exited and control goes to the catch block.

Comment: What @ernest_k says. Perhaps also extract some methods in your loops to make it more readable / maintainable. Since try and catch clauses in for loops tend to get messy

Answer (score 1):

You should create some validation methods that will return `boolean` that means the validation was successful. Than you can use do while loop for asking for the input once again in case of a `ValidationError`. Something like this:

```
do {    
      System.out.print("Enter a Number: ");
      String userInput = new Scanner(System.in).next();
  } while (!validate(userInput));

num.add(Integer.parseInt(userInput));
```

You can also use the `Scanner.hasNextInt()` mtehod before trying to read int if the only restriction is to have valid int number.